# The Area 51 lookup link redirects to the wrong site proposal page for sites that have been proposed more than once

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, hyperlinks

Currently if you go to the newly launched beta site for [AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f) you'll see the:

> To log in, you must have commited to the [Area 51 site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/ai.stackexchange.com) and received the invitation email. Click the invitation link in the email to log in!

Which redirects to the old closed proposal from 3 years ago: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence

Instead of the new one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence

Additionally since you can now participate in a site's closed beta by going through the "[Visit the site now!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence/visit)" link. The wording on the log in description should be changed from "received the invitation email. Click the invitation link in the email to log in!" to reflect this.

Just to be picky: "commited" is spelled "committed" (you missed a "t" there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a good case study on the dangers of replicating AIs.  The link should be fixed now.  I'll get back to you on the extra 't'.  We need to find a dictionary.  ;-)

Comment: Any luck finding a dictionary?